# Can we increase update quota in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to increase update quota on bigquery. As I will update around 1m rows update per day , how can i do this.

I have a table in Bigquery which need around 1M update per day.

Current record count in Bigquery table = 62000000

Below is error I'm getting:

```
  {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "Quota exceeded:  (truncated...)
  }
```

Comment: Do you actually need to `UPDATE` that many times? It would be easier and cheaper just to append data continuously, and then you can select the most recent row for the attributes that you care about. You can create a logical view with the "most recent" logic, too.

Comment: but we need to update data as we are working on user profiling

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery is primarly designed and suit to append-only technology with some limited DML statements.

It's not a realtional database where you constantly update your user records if they edit their profile. Instead you need to arhitect your code so each edit is a new row in Bigquery, and you always query the latest row.

The DML statement limitation is low, because it targets different scenarios and not yours, aka live update on rows. You could ingest your data into a separate table, and issue 1 update statement per day.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery removed the DML quota limits, so here after you will not receive the above error.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery